# Build passes but seems JMeter test is not running through Maven CMD command

Tags: maven, jmeter

I am trying to execute my *JMeter* scripts through *Maven*. I am using *Jmeter 5.3* and I am using below pom.xml.

When I execute it through command prompt `mvn verify -Dusers=1 -DrampUp=1 -Dloopcount=1 -Durl=1 -DSmokeDemoTest=1`, it shows me the build success message but seems it is not executing my *JMeter* test script that's why I am not getting JTL report file in target folder. I am attaching command prompt execution screenshot. Could you please suggest and help me out on this issue.

POMXML:
[image: POMXML1]

CommandPromptExecution Image:
[image: CommandPromptExecution Image]

Answer (score 0):

Your test is running fine, the only problem is that there are 0 samplers executed therefore there are no results.

From your very beautiful screenshot of the *pom.xml* file it's not very clear how do you define the `users` property, you should have something like:

```
<properties>
    <users>1</users>
    <rampUp>1</rampUp>
    <loopcount>1</loopcount>
    <url>http://example.com</url>
    <suite>foo</suite> 
</properties>
```

in the beginning of your pom.xml file.

Once done the properties will be declared and you will be able to override them via -D command-line argument.

Also make sure to properly reference the properties in JMeter test plan using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)

[image]

If you will still be experiencing problems check the [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file(s) under `target/jmeter/logs` folder for any suspicious entries

More information:

- [How to create user defined properties in Maven](https://mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-user-defined-properties-in-maven/)
- [How to Use the JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin)